# Designing a system that supports overrides, file_exists() and includes?

Tags: php, architecture, overriding, scalability

I have a very module-based architecture in my infosystem that is installed to hundreds of clients. Updates are loaded to those clients automatically. But some of these clients have custom functionality that I do not want to add footprint to every other client out there.

Thus I want to implement overrides into the system, so that certain modules act a little differently from the main system.

First idea I had was about having bunch of file_exists() checks before including files and classes, to see if there is an override version of it in overrides directory, but the system loads a lot of files, which would mean there would have to be around twenty to thirty file_exists() checks per page load (this includes files like CSS and JavaScript too).

Would that be appropriate or is there a better way to design an infosystem that has 99% of the clients on one codebase and 1% using overrides on some of the functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: check it only when installing/reinstalling, I don't think this checks would be a performance headache

Comment: You may consider having a configuration file which specifies overrides. Then you'll know exactly what needs to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with *user973254* and *Michael Mior*'s comments, and think that you should combine them: when installing, perform the checks for the overrides, then use the info to generate a config script - just store an array of `$modules['ModuleName'] = '/File/Path'`. Then, whenever you load a module call `include $modules['ModuleName'];`

Comment: I did exactly that and saved couple of milliseconds of execution time. The same principle is also useful for some other things that can only change after update, so it's a good way to go about it. Cheers!